# @ResponseBody to choose different response format

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm quite new to Spring MVC. Today when I learn `@ResponseBody`, I have some questions about `HttpMessageConverter`s:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As above, we could declare a list of different converters. So it means we could choose one of them as response body converter.

But how to choose the one to use? For example, in `functionA()` to return JSON and then in `functionB()` to return XML.

My way is to force `Content-Type` of response, is it a correct way? Or does a better solution exist?

```
public @ResponseBody User getUser(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/xml");         
    // SOME CODES HERE
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how to choose the one to use? For example, in functionA() to
>   return JSON and then in functionB() to return XML

You can use `RequestMapping`'s `produces` attribute for that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Something functionA () { ... }
```

And:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/b", produces = "application/xml")
public @ResponseBody Something functionB () { ... }
```

Also, you can omit the `produces` and *Be more liberal in what you accept from clients*. With this approach you let the client choose between `XML`, `JSON` or whatever through a process called *Content Negotiation* using `Accept` header. In fact, if client fire a request like:

```
GET /a HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
```

`functionA` will return a JSON representation of the return value, and if client send this request:

```
GET /a HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
```

`functionA` will return an XML representation of the return value.

Comment: by the way it's better to add "; charset=utf-8" to produces.

Comment: Thank you, very clear idea!! For more details, we could only set 'produces' with the Contetn-type supported by converters defined in RequestMappingHandlerAdapter? Or it already supports some converters like JSON or String, we do not need to declare them explicitly in xml config files?

Comment: Each `HttpMessageConverter` has a `getSupportedMediaTypes` which defines what media types this converter can handle. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: And yes there should be an appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` for each media type you use for `produces` and `consumes`. Some of them are registered by default, others should be registered manually.

Comment: @AliDehghani Well understand it now. I checked [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody). HttpMessageConverters has four converters by default, so I think these four do not need to declare automatically for RequestBody and ResponseBody annotation

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url1", produces = "application/json")
```

for json and use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url2", produces = "application/xml")
```

for xml output